# Twitter trends: how to fetch top 100 most used words?

Tags: twitter

For a research project, I need to download the top 100 most used words on Twitter, multiple times per hour. However, as far as I can tell, [the Twitter API](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/trends/current) only supports downloading the top 10 most used words ("trends").

My questions therefore are:

1. Am I missing something in the API? Is there another way to fetch more than 10 trends?
2. If there isn't, does anybody know of a workaround for this problem?

Comment: If you don't get the answer you are looking for here, I suggest you ask your question at the official Twitter [API discussions boards](https://dev.twitter.com/discussions/rest-streaming-api).  If you learn how do accomplish this, be sure to post your answer here for others.

Answer (score 3):

Put `?count=50` at the end of the URL to get the top 50. I haven't been able to get more than 50.

```
http://api.twitter.com/1/trends/current.json?count=50
```

Answer (score 0):

you should monitor your timeline get all tweets , save in database, analyze via NLP, and save words(for example person names), after aggregate and get counts, for example "Obama 50 times, Java 10 times, linux 5 times"